# Using a preset variable to pull a column name, then use it within a query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a pricing system for a bookings company, I have a DataBase table full of prices. A typical row looks like this:

```
priceID  |  manufac  |  model  |  janDay  | janWeek  |  febDay  |  febWeek  |  etc etc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |Chevrolelt |  Matiz  |  40.00   |  133.00  |  40.00   |  133.00   |  etc etc
```

Basically I have a variable:

```
$startmonth
```

This variable is set by my code finiding out the month, and depending on its number assigning it a value. In this instance lets assume that it has gone through that and obtained the value:

```
$startmonth = 'febWeek';
```

I then have another query that finds out the model of a car, I have tested this and it returns the model, so we know that:

```
$model = 'Matiz';
```

Then I execute another query to gain the price:

```
$getprice = mysql_query("SELECT '".$startmonth."' FROM prices WHERE model = '".$model."' ");
while($ppdrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getprice)) {

   $priceperday = $ppdrow;

}
```

I have tried this query numerous ways and I always end up with errors or an undesirable result. When it should return **133.00**.

What it actually returns:

```
( [2] => 2 )
```

I am proobably doing something really stupid, but can anyone tell me what please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query instead:

```
$getprice = mysql_query("SELECT `".$startmonth."` FROM prices WHERE model = '".$model."' ");
```

Note the backticks (around the column name) in the place of the single quotes.

And as for the while loop, you are trying to set `$priceperday` equal to `$ppdrow`, which is an array. You want to set it to the correct value (column) *within* the array:

```
while($ppdrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getprice)) {
   $priceperday = $ppdrow[$startmonth];
}
```

Please also read about [why not to use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: backtick does what exactly? just so I know. :) Thank you for the answer.

Comment: A delimiter isn't actually neccessary in an SQL query, UNLESS the column/table name is the same as a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). In which case, the backticks tell MySQL *this is a name of a column/table, not a reserved word*

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$getprice = mysql_query("SELECT ".$startmonth." FROM prices WHERE model ='".$model."'   ");
while($ppdrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getprice)) {

 $priceperday = $ppdrow[$startmonth];

}
```